# Remove only the whitespaces in array but not the 0(Zero) number

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm trying to remove white spaces in a multidimensional array. But the integer 0 is included in removing.

I've already tried array_filter and array_map to remove it.

```
$a="array(
      [0] => test
      [1] => 0
      [2] => test
      [3] => 
      [4] => 
      [5] => test
)
array(
      [0] => test
      [1] => 
      [2] => 
      [3] => 
      [4] => 0
      [5] => test
)"
$b=array_filter(array_map('trim', $a));
print_r($b);
```

The output is

```
"array(
      [0] => test
      [2] => test
      [5] => test
)
array(
      [0] => test
      [5] => test
)"
```

But the expected output should be like this

```
"array(
      [0] => test
      [1] => 0
      [2] => test
      [5] => test
)
array(
      [0] => test
      [4] => 0
      [5] => test
)"
```

Comment: Array_filter is the issue, not `trim`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#111091

Comment: ohhh so in my code im filtering even the 0 value, i guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with the help of `array_filter()` and `strlen`

```
$result = [];
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    // strlen will remove all NULL, FALSE and empty strings but leaves 0 values
    $result[$k] =  array_filter( $v, 'strlen' );
}
print_r($result);
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/chq3D

Comment: i cannot implement the foreach function, but i used the array_filter( $v, 'strlen' ); and it worked!!! thank you.